# getting viewable_id null using cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable package

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to count views from every post using this package, but I'm not getting the viewable_id on database.
Here is my Post.php (model)

```
    <?php 
namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use CyrildeWit\EloquentViewable\Viewable;
class Post extends Model
{  
use Viewable;
  // ...
}
```

my PostsController.php

```
  public function show(Post $posts)
{

  $posts->addView();
  return view('posts.show', compact('posts'));
}
```

and my table create_views_table.php is default from the package.
version of cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable is 2.1 .
Do I need something else to add to get the viewable_id. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the installation guide here: https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable#installation ?

Remember the step to publish migrations and run them.

Comment: Yes I did, I published two things that they asked.

Comment: Did you change the primary key of the `Post` model to something other than `id`?

Comment: I'm not getting it, but i did not change nothing to the Post model.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue .http://prntscr.com/k4pjcn

Answer (score 1):

This issue because of routing, there must be parameter to page tou have to define like this
Route::get('/sales-support/{post}', 'SupportController@sales')->name('createSalesSupport');

And pass parameter to url http://127.0.0.1:8000/sales-support/3

for more info visit https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable/issues/83